# Any way to have the default HTTP Authentication redirect to a template when user fails to authenticate?

Tags: authentication, http

Referring to https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/template_access.html#http-authentication

Right now a failed or canceled authentication redirects to the standard server 401 page.

Is there any way to have this redirect to a specific url?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the EE source (v.2.10.1) you will see the following in `system/expressionengine/libraries/Auth.php` (*line numbers on the left*):

```
156                 if ($authed === FALSE)
157                 {
158                         @header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="'.$realm.'"');
159                         ee()->output->set_status_header(401);
160                         @header("Date: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
161                         exit("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
162                 }
```

EE's authentication hijacks the 401 response, dumping out a header and using PHP's `exit()` function to dump out an "helpful" text string. AFAIK, and based on this evidence, there is no way to catch a 401 HTTP error code in a template, or even a raw Apache directive, *without* hacking the EE source, which is not recommended.

I have submitted this as a [bug to Ellis Labs](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21034/no-ability-to-create-custom-401-or-403-http-code-error-pages) but have no heard anything back yet. If I do, I will add it to my own [SO question that is similar to this](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/32492).

Comment: Cheers mate, keeping an eye on this one.

Comment: It doesn't "hijack the 401 response"; since PHP is being called upon to provide the HTTP Auth mechanism at this point, it is PHP's responsibility to throw a 401 on failed authentication. http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php AFAIK, it is not possible to let Apache handle this ErrorDocument unless Apache is providing the HTTP Auth mechanism.